# Databases Failed to load in cloudant data layer local edition 1.1

Tags: cloudant

We have lost all databases from cloudant and as there is no option we restored data folders from file system backup and try to restart cloudant.
Facing the below issue and errors.
Please help us in resolving the issue.[Databases failed to load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0d4j.png)

Getting this error as below:
{"error":"internal_server_error","reason":"No DB shards could be opened.","ref":1747618916}

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved after restoring the shards directory as there are some files missing from the restored backup and then restart cloudant